# Upload Int in background to Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to integrate a "vote" function in my app using Parse (parse.com) to store the data.
My problem is that when I try to send the vote++ to the server, it doesn't go.
Here is the source code :

Model :

```
class PARSESearch {
var votes:Int?

init(pfObject: PFObject) {
self.votes = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
}

func toPFObject() -> PFObject {
let planeObject = PFObject(className: "Search")
planeObject["votes"] = votes
return planeObject
}
```

And the implementation in a function of the viewController :

```
var parseObject:PFObject?

        if(parseObject != nil) {
        if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            votes!++

            //parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes");
            parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes");
            parseObject!.saveInBackground();

            votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!)";
        }
    }
```

May the problem come from the fact that I just have parseObject:PFObject? and it is not referring to any classes or anything else ?

I hope that you can help me, I'm 14 so if you could provide source code it would really help me :)

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the solution is :

```
       var query = PFQuery(className: "Search")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(parseSearch.objectId) {
        (votes: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            if let votes = votes {
                votes.incrementKey("votes")
                votes.saveInBackground()
            }
        }
    }
```

You can find objects, queries... on parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

when you set object this time votes is int type while it should be an object. Try modified code and let me know if it works.

```
if(parseObject != nil) {
        if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            votes!++

            //parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes");
            parseObject!.setObject(votes! as? String, forKey: "votes");
            parseObject!.saveInBackground();

            votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!)";
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, your code is not working... I was asking myself if it wasn't because of the "parseObject" because it don't refer to any class name or anything

Comment: no still not, but I tried with "parseObject!.setObject((votes! as? String)!, forKey: "votes");" because with your code I have an error : "Value of optional type String? not unwrapped" but already thanks for helping me :)

Comment: hmm I'm also new to swift try looking at parse forums for this.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me ! You can find my answer up